# VB6 Scrolled object spilling out of its container

Tags: vb6

I'm trying to create a scrolling area containing other controls to allow large, varying amounts of data to be entered. I'm doing this by creating a frame, in which is another frame and a scroll bar. The scroll bar moves the inner frame up and down so all the controls may be brought into view.

However, the inner frame is spilling out of the outer frame during scrolling. I was wondering first, if this is the correct approach, and if it is, how to prevent that spillage?

It's mostly a cosmetic problem so there's no need to worry about it if the answer is complicated, but it would be nice to be able to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the standard way to create a scrollable container in VB6 - although it's traditional to use a PictureBox as the inner container rather than a Frame, e.g. in the [classic book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Programming-Microsoft%C2%AE-Visual-Basic%C2%AE-6-0/dp/0735605580).

The inner frame should be "clipped" by the outer frame: any parts of the inner frame that exceed the bounds of the outer frame should not be visible. Is the inner frame definitely contained within the outer frame?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I believe so; the inner frame moves around when I move the outer one around in the development environment. Studying the dialogue carefully, it may be that the inner frame actually does stay inside the outer frame's limits, but overwrites the actual drawing of the frame, which is a little within that area.

Comment: @Brian Curious. Maybe that's why everyone uses a PictureBox for the innner container! I just looked at an old project where I did something like this, and I've used a borderless PictureBox for the inner container and a borderless Frame for the outer container. I also have ClipControls and AutoRedraw on for the PictureBox and parent form. I have a vague memory of some problems getting a satisfactory appearance, possibly similar to what you describe, but I couldn't swear to it.

Comment: Thanks; I've removed the border from the outer frame, so it doesn't get overwritten and nobody will care it isn't there.